# Scraping website - getting links in weird format

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, xhtml, puppeteer

Im trying to scrape a website with Puppeteer and the links Im getting back are in a weird format.

The links (parsed by a dom parser via node server) look like this:

```
{ type: 'tag',
     name: 'a',
     namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
     attribs:
      { 'data-ng-click': 'saveUserChoice()',
        class: 'link link-dashed' },
     'x-attribsNamespace': { 'data-ng-click': undefined, class: undefined },
     'x-attribsPrefix': { 'data-ng-click': undefined, class: undefined },
     children: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     parent:
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'div',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: [Object],
        'x-attribsNamespace': [Object],
        'x-attribsPrefix': [Object],
        children: [Array],
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Object] },
     prev:
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n                ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: null,
        next: [Circular] },
     next:
      { type: 'text',
        data: '\n            ',
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Circular],
        next: null } },

}
```

Any idea why this is or how to proceed? I cant tell if its because the page is formatted as a single page app, or the website is doing something to prevent scraping.

Comment: This is Angular data.  I recognize the `data-ng-click` attribute.

Comment: Thanks - how would I click an element on an angular page programatically? I was trying to grab elements via puppeteer with the id but its not able to find any of them

Comment: Is there a way to programatically get access to the data coming from the headful version?

Comment: Closing - figured this out by looking at the xhr requests in Chrome